# Slf4j FileAppender Problem "it is being used by another process"

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, logback, slf4j

We have Scheduled job to write to db from these log files. However, even if append is false, files will be locked. How can I solve this problem?

Btw, I am changing the extension log to xml. It can't happen also..

Thanks.

```
<sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${fileLocation}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>${fileLocation}.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
```

Comment: public class XXXAppender extends SiftingAppender {

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
        super.append(event);
        if(eventMarksEndOfLife(event)){
            getAppenderTracker().removeStaleComponents(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            getAppenderTracker().setTimeout(1000L);
        }
    }

    protected boolean eventMarksEndOfLife(ILoggingEvent event) {

        Marker marker = event.getMarker();
        if (marker == null)
            return false;

        return marker.contains(ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER);
    }
}

Comment: before request is over, you have to set   log.trace(ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER,"");